# Check Array Element When Push Element

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

i am using JS Array

```
var fruits = [['5','7'],['10','20'],['20','30']];

function myFunction() {
    // want to check Here
    fruits.push(['30', '40']); // allow
    fruits.push(['7', '10']); // allow
    fruits.push(['10', '12']); // Should not allow
    fruits.push(['5', '35']); // Should not allow
}
```

i want to check and allow the Elements in array.

Comment: At what exact condition should an element be accepted or not? I am confused

Comment: if i push (['30', '40']); it should allow, if i push (['5', '35']); should not allow.

Comment: is the fruit array sorted?

Comment: No jokes, I can read a question. Why is `[30, 40]` allowed and not `[5, 35]`? I understand you want to get min and max of all the numbers in the array of arrays, and the pushed element must have values outside of min and max. Correct?

Comment: its not Related to Min and Max, for any interval, Let me Update my question

Comment: I think the key to the question is "overlap." Think of the array elements as ranges. The OP wants all ranges to be distinct from each other. No overlaps. I don't think there is a requirement that the array be sorted,

Comment: Array `['5','35']` is not overlapped.

Comment: @Pugazh, Ignore if the value is Same, check (7,10) and (10,12)

Answer (score 4):

With unsorted data, you could check every border and push `array` if no overlapping occurs.

```js
function push(array) {
    return fruits.every(function(a) {
        return array[1] <= a[0] || a[1] <= array[0];
    }) && fruits.push(array) && true;
}

var fruits = [[10, 15], [25, 30]];

console.log(push([5, 35]));  // false
console.log(push([30, 40])); // true
console.log(push([15, 25])); // true
console.log(push([5, 10]));  // true
console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: Can you check this solution? After `var fruits = [[10, 15], [25, 30]];` I am getting `true` for `push([5,35])`.

Comment: Also a fun problem for golfing: `push=a=>fruits.every(b=>(a[1]<=b[0]||b[1]<=a[0]))&&fruits.push(a)&&true`

Comment: I have a Keys like 0,1,2... how can i work with this

Comment: @AbdulWaheed, what do you mean with "*Keys like 0,1,2*"?

Comment: @NinaScholz, Yes, i have Multiple Row, for difference row, values might be Same, i have to Combine the solution with Key.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going this route:

```
class IntervalList {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [];
  }
  add(low, high) {
    if (low > high) {
      [low, high] = [high, low];
    }
    for (let [x,y] of this.data) {
      if (x < low) {
        if (y > low) return false;
      } else if (x > low) {
        if (x < high) return false;
      }
    }
    this.data.push([low, high]);
    return true;
  } 
}
```

Then you say things like

```
let c = new IntervalList();
c.add(10, 20);
c.add(20, 30);
c.add(5,7);
c.add(3,5);
c.add(9,7)
```

Let the data structure maintain itself.

Note that what you want to do is tricky. Some people might erroneously think you that to check if (p,q) overlaps (r,s) you just have to check whether p is between r and s or q is between r and s. THIS IS NOT TRUE. Because if the values were arranged "p r s q" that algorithm would fail. Note how the above algorithm looks weird but it takes care of that case. That is why the problem is interesting.